# How do you combine tuples with repeating attributes into one tuple?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, arraylist, jdbc

I created a java class with the same name as a table from a SQL database, and using the retrieved information from that table I created multiple objects out of that Java class, and stored them inside An ArrayList.

```
CREATE TABLE `orderdetails` (
  `orderNumber` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `productCode` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `quantityOrdered` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `priceEach` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
  `orderLineNumber` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`orderNumber`,`productCode`),
  KEY `productCode` (`productCode`),
  CONSTRAINT `orderdetails_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`orderNumber`) REFERENCES `orders` (`orderNumber`),
  CONSTRAINT `orderdetails_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`productCode`) REFERENCES `products` (`productCode`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

tuples have repeating orderNumbers, for example:

```
(10100,'S18_1749',30,'136.00',3),

(10100,'S18_2248',50,'55.09',2),

(10100,'S18_4409',22,'75.46',4),
```

Each tuple is then turned into a java object of the class with the same name as the table, and to be stored inside an Arraylist.

```
public ArrayList<OrderDetails> getOrders(String tableName) throws SQLException{
        ArrayList<OrderDetails>od=new ArrayList<OrderDetails>();

        try {
            String query="SELECT * FROM "+tableName;
            Statement s= con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs= s.executeQuery(query);

            while(rs.next()) {

                int orderNumber=rs.getInt("orderNumber");
                String productCode=rs.getString("productCode");
                int quantityOrdered=rs.getInt("quantityOrdered");
                double priceEach=rs.getDouble("priceEach");
                int orderLineNumber=rs.getInt("orderLineNumber");

                OrderDetails temp=new OrderDetails(orderNumber, productCode, quantityOrdered, priceEach, orderLineNumber);
                od.add(temp);

            }

        }
        catch(SQLException e) {

            System.out.println("SQL exception happened while retriving data, close connection");

            throw new RuntimeException(e);  
        }
        return od;
    }
```

I am trying to Loop through the ArrayList and output the total amount of value (priceEach times quantityOrdered )for each checkNumber. But if I simply just loop through the ArrayList one object by object, that isn't going to work. As I will simply see the sum for each object, not each checkNumber, on the console.

```
ArrayList<OrderDetails>od= this.getOrders("orderdetails");
for(int i=0;i<=od.size();i++) {
         System.out.println(od.get(i).getPriceEach()*od.get(i).getQuantityOrdered());

     }
```

I'm expecting something like this to show up on console (no repeating checkNumber)

```
CheckNumber 10100, total value: 8494.62 (if you add up the product between priceEach and quantityOrdered for the three tuples shown above earlier in my question is the rsult)
```

In short is there a way for me to combine objects with repeating attributes into one? 
I apologize if my question seems very vague and you don't know exactly what the problem is. 
It would be greatly appreciated if you try to reach out for me and ask for further clarifications, sometimes it is very difficult to describe a problem that's too specific..

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply do the computation in the database? SQL is a set-based language that is very efficient at this type of operation, compared to an iterative loop in Java.

Consider the following aggregate query:

```
select orderNumber, sum(quantityOrdered * priceEach) totalValue
from mytable
group by orderNumber
```

This gives you one record per order, with the total value over all corresponding rows.

Comment: That sounds like a great idea! But because this coursework is meant for me to practise dynamic Java programming I'm afraid I can't be using complex SQL statements.... However thanks for the suggestion though!